# to upate the data inside the Adapter after notifyDataSetChanged is called

Tags: android, android-listview

I am populating the list view using BaseAdapter. I am initializing the content variable inside adapter's constructor. Content is a singleton instance. constructor is the only place where i will set the content variable. Once i call notifyDataSetChanged(), how the new data will be populated to the variable. as far as i know constructor will be called only once when the object is created. Then i need to get the data everytime during the getView() is called. basically how to update the data inside adapter once the notifyDataSetChanged is called? I can have some public methods in adapter like setData(Content). But i am looking for some methods that BaseAdapter will provide that i can override to set the content.

```
MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

List<ContentItems> mContent;
public myAdapter() {
  mContent = Content.getInstance().getContent();       
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  mContent.get(position)
  //using the content create view and return
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have everything you need, when you call **notifyDataSetChanged** mContent should be automatically updated, and in the getView method you can populate your view with the data.
getView will be automatically called when you call notifyDataSetChanged, and if you implement it correctly it will, put the new data into your view.

PS: I don't know if this is important to you, but getView will only be called for the positions that fit into the screen. If you got more data then initially visible, getView will render out the other data when the view that holds the data becomees visible (e.g. when you have a ListView and you start scrolling down).